# Spring Boot gradle multi module application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a spring boot application (gradle) with multi modules but having issues when I build the application. Below is my gradle

**build.gradle (Main application)**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'net.sagati'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compile project(':my-pet-clinic-data')
    compile project(':my-pet-clinic-web')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**build.gradle - Data layer. First module**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'net.sagati'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

**build.gradle - web layer 2nd module**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'net.sagati'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

********************error message ****************************************

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':my-pet-clinic-data'.
> Could not find method bootJar() for arguments [build_iptt1011gxtkxqsop7ht18yc$_run_closure4@45139c47] on project ':my-pet-clinic-data' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**update**

after removing

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
```

I'm getting below error

```
Execution failed for task ':my-pet-clinic-data:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':my-pet-clinic-data:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.projectlombok:lombok:.
     Required by:
         project :my-pet-clinic-data
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:.
     Required by:
         project :my-pet-clinic-data
```

Comment: What is the issue? What error message are you getting?

Comment: updated the error message

Comment: And what Gradle command are you using?

Comment: And shouldn't your web module depend on the data module?

Answer (score 0):

The updated issue is caused by not having any version for the dependencies.

When applying the Spring boot Gradle plugin, it applies the Spring dependency managment plugin and configures the Spring boot BOM. This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/).

However your data and web projects only apply the `java` plugin and thus have no support for a BOM. I would recommend looking into the [native Gradle BOM support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import). An alternative, with a performance cost, can be found in the Spring documentation linked above, section 3.2.