# Unable to integration-testing gradle multi-module Spring-Boot-Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, multi-module

Within a Gradle multi-module project with the bootstrapping in its own module I'm unable to use [MockMvc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/), because its need to reference the bootstrapping-module. I'm not sure if I have misconfigured something. The basic structure is:

- module: a module containing some REST-Services and needs a testImplementation-Dependency on starter
- starter: the bootstrapping-module which gets the spring-boot-plugin applied and depends on module

I have set up a minimal example on [github](https://github.com/gaerfield/spring-multimodule-integrationtest) using Spring-Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE and Gradle 6.4 with the following configuration:

*./settings.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "spring-multimodule-integrationtest"
include("starter", "module")
```

*./build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
subprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        apply(plugin = "java-library")
        "testImplementation"("junit:junit:4.12")
    }
}
```

*./starter/build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.1.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":module"))
}
```

*./module/build.gradle.kts*

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation(project(":starter"))
}
```

The *starter*-module contains only one a single class "Starter" referencing the *module*-module:

```java
public class Starter {
    public String info() { return "starter"; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Starter().info() + " and " + new Module().info());
    }
}
```

The *module*-module (*sigh I should have chosen a different name for this module) contains only this  implemenation-class:

```java
public class Module {
    public String info() { return "module"; }
}
```

Additionally, the *module*-module has the following test-class doing the integration-test:

```java
public class IntegrationTest
{
    @Test public void testSomeLibraryMethod() {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
        Starter.main(new String[0]);
        assertEquals("starter and module\n", out.toString());
    }
}
```

This code runs fine until the applying of the spring-boot-plugin within "./starter/build.gradle.kts". When the tasks "clean test" issued on the shell I get:

```
❯ ./gradlew clean test

> Task :module:test FAILED

de.kramhal.multi.IntegrationTest > testSomeLibraryMethod FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at IntegrationTest.java:17
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at IntegrationTest.java:17

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

This problem does not occur, when tests are executed within the IDE (IntelliJ to be exact).

I already tried unsuccessfully to use the spring-dependency-management as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496709/5029667) (as well as in several other answers).

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would recommend restructuring your project so you don't have cyclic dependencies. As it is now, in order to build `starter`, you need to build `module`. And in order to test `module`, you need to build `starter`. Gradle can do it, but it is usually a smell.

In terms of troubleshooting: when you get a test failure like this, look at the test report as that has the full stack trace. You should see that it complains that it can't find the `Starter` class (`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.kramhal.multi.Starter`), which is of cause in the `starter` module.

You mentioned the `spring-dependency-management` plugin, but that is only relevant for managing Maven dependencies, and not project dependencies like this. So it is not helpful here.

I am not entirely sure if this is Windows specific or not as I remember there were some discussions around performance a while back when having a lot of classes. But I believe the `java-library` plugin will look for jar files in other projects, and not the folder for compiled classes. This is a problem for you since the `spring-boot` plugin will by default disable the standard `jar` task and instead create "fat" a jar file through the `bootJar` task. Because you need both the fat jar for packaging the application to run  stand-alone but also the normal jar for consuming it as a dependency, you need to do some tweaks to the `starter` project (Kotlin DSL):

```kotlin
tasks {
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }
    bootJar {
        archiveClassifier.set("boot")
    }
}
```

This will enable the normal jar file, but because the name will conflict with the one produced by the `bootJar` task, you need to rename one of them. I chose to rename the `bootJar` one.

I don't know why the test works for you in IntelliJ as that should, by default, delegate everything to Gradle. But maybe you have an old version, or done some manual configuration to let IntelliJ both compile and run your tests.

Comment: Sir! Thank you very much for the explanation. I haven't got the idea from looking at the failure, that the jar was missing itself is missing. And I could have had come to this idea, as it was already explained [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16689#issuecomment-487984729) by wilkinsona.
Also, I now see that the link was irritating as it goes to the dependency-management instead of [packaging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal).

Comment: Regarding circular dependency: I know it's unusual and personally I would prefer to not let tests depend on a different module.
Implementing integration-tests with MockMvc (needing to know the "SpringBootApplication"-annotated class), which option is there?
I could only think of creating a separate module coffee-integration-test depending on starter and coffee (same for cashier).

Comment: To be a bit more clear about the intention of the architecture:
* module **starter**: as described = only bootstrapping the application and therefore depending on everything else
* module **coffee**: rest-services for ordering coffees in awkward variants (vanilla, ginger, ...)
* module **cashier**: rest-services for paying orders
The modules coffee and cashier don't need to know about each other, from architectural view its good practice to keep them separated. Multi-Module allows keeping them together in a single project as monolith, making them easier to handle (deploy and develop).

Comment: You don't need to apply the spring-boot plugin to test with MockMvc. The plugin is only for the final packaging as a stand-alone jar (or war). You also don't need a SpringBootApplication-annotated class to test your Spring controllers. I would probably not depend on the `starter` module at all, but rather just test the modules' functionality in isolation. And then have a full-blown integration tests with all modules in either the application module (`starter`) or a single separate module for testing. That is not to say your way is wrong, I just never seen it done like that before :)