# spring reuse test context and avoiding circular dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit

I can‘t seem to figure this out. Project A (which is the core Project where the @SpringBootApplication resides) has a dependency in its pom to project B. Project A imports the configuration of Project B to register the beans  of project B with the @Import Annotation. Project B contains the Configuration that gets imported by A and the Beans that are referenced in that Configuration, thats it. A lot of Unit Tests that I write just @Autowired a Bean that I wanna test and check the behaviour. So there exists an abstract class that every unit test inherits.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { FooConfig.class, FooTestConfig.class})
public abstract TestContext {}
```

```
@Configuration
@Import(BarConfig.class)
public class FooConfig {

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class BarConfig {

    public BarBean BarBean () {}
}
```

Now I could just write the test to the Beans of Project B in Project A (that works!) But I want the tests for the Beans in Project B to reside in Project B and not A. When I add a dependency to Project A (test-jar)in the pom.xml of B, I could in theory just inherit the abstract "TestContext" that would work but maven tells me:

`Annotation processing is not supported for module cycles.`

And rightfully so because Project A depends on B and vice versa. If I write the Unit Test to the Beans in Project B then it works but I want the test to the Beans to reside in Project B.

This is what I want:

```
Project A
├── _main/java/packageName
│   ├── FooConfig.java
├── test/java/packageName
│   ├── FooTestConfig.java
│   ├── TestContext.java

Project B
├── main/java/packageName
│   ├── BarBean.java
│   ├── BarConfig.java
├── test/java/packageName
│   ├── BarBeanTest.java
```

This is not what I want but this works:

```
Project A
├── _main/java/packageName
│   ├── FooConfig.java
├── test/java/packageName
│   ├── FooTestConfig.java
│   ├── TestContext.java
│   ├── BarBeanTest.java

Project B
├── main/java/packageName
│   ├── BarConfig.java
│   ├── BarBean.java
├── test/java/packageName
│
```

The test would look sth like this, if there wasn't a circular dependency:

```
public class BarBeanTest extends TestContext {

   @Autowired
   BarBean barBean;
}
```

I know that one solution would be to create a third Project C to resolve the cyclic dependency but I haven't figured out yet how to provide the TestContext of Project A to other projects.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet but if anyone finds my question this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340841/unable-to-integration-testing-gradle-multi-module-spring-boot-application

Comment: I've found another possible solutions but its probably not cleanest because theres more code to maintain, but this makes it possible to modularize your tests. But it doesnt't seem possible to set a contextconfiguration for the test in other modules ( In my example Project B)

Comment: For now I'm going to keep my tests in Project A, and If I build my Project without Project B Ill just ignore the test for the Beans in Project B via Profiles